# viewDidLoad called before an IBAction?

Tags: methods, action, viewdidload

in my Xcode project I have a button, that does two things.

First: call an IBAction
Second: go to another view (segue)

In the action linked to the button I set a variable to YES (global var), but in the viewDidLoad method in the linked view, its still NO. Its YES in viewDidAppear though. I wonder why the action is not called first. Can I change that? I'd prefer to use the viewDidLoad method, since it seems to load quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `prepareForSegue` method to pass whatever data to the destination view before the segue assigned to the button is performed. This data will be available in the destination view `viewDidLoad`

Comment: thank you! but i just realized, the viewDidLoad method only is loaded once, right? its not appropriate for me anyway.

Comment: `ViewDidLoad` is called once when the controller is loaded. If the controller is unloaded and loaded again, it will be called again.

Comment: makes sense, but when is it loaded again? when i close and restart the app?